# I have got the certificate with browser, How can I do a request to the https server with the certificate for avoiding domain hijacking?

Tags: java, https

I need to do a request `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`. I have got the certificate with browser. How can I avoid domain hijacking with the certificate for request to the url with java?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the https url and correctly validate the certificate (including the revocation), you should be fine.

Example in java: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/simple-https-example

```
URL myurl = new URL("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
```

Comment: How can I validate the certificate? I have added the certificate to the trustManager when I do a request with httpclient, It will be fine  even though  I  appoint the domain to my test ip with hosts. So I think I don't get the right way.

Comment: @brouth I've add an example